# How to 'pause' Tkinter mainloop()?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-idle, tkinter-canvas

I have a simple program:

I have a Tk canvas widget and want to update that as I put in commands. But since the event loop is already running, how do I tell it to pause shortly, process my command and resume, now drawing the updated version of my canvas?

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, width=200, height=200)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.oval = canvas.create_oval(20,20,40,40)

    def changeoval(self):
        self.canvas.destroy(self.oval)
        self.oval = canvas.create_oval(40,40,60,60)


window = App()
mainloop()

.
.
.

window.changeoval()
```

What I mean by "put in commands" is the IDLE shell. You can run a program there and interact with it. I would run the above code WITHOUT the window.changeoval() in IDLE and then type `window.changeoval()` into the shell and I want it to update my canvas with the newly situated oval.

Comment: If you're working in IDLE or a similar interactive Python shell, don't use `window.mainloop()`. These shells are specially set up to not block input during the GUi loop.

Comment: The previous question referenced above is factually obsolete (it claimed that `mainloop` was required on Windows to get a tk window)  and has a wrong answer ('IDLE cannot run tkinter apps').  TigerhawkT3 's comment above is correct.  I routinely change widget options interactively to see the effect and decide on the value to put in a program.